# Collection View Height

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using a height constraint to decrease the height of a collection view when keyboard pops up.

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 250 - keyboardSize.height/2
        self.addButtonConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height+20

    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = 250
    self.addButtonConstraint.constant = 20

      }
}
```

[image]

How can I make collection view show first half rather than last half?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to call this in keyboardWillShow method:

```
collectionView.scrollToTop(false)
```

Extension

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollToTop(_ animated: Bool) {
        var topContentOffset: CGPoint
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            topContentOffset = CGPoint(x: -safeAreaInsets.left, y: -safeAreaInsets.top)
        } else {
            topContentOffset = CGPoint(x: -contentInset.left, y: -contentInset.top)
        }
        setContentOffset(topContentOffset, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think author meant to show the top part of his collection view and you are retrieving an index for the last section. But the logic is pretty much the same

Comment: That's my bad.. thought asking moving to bottom. Answer was edited